# How do I auth in Jenkins CLI without showing my password

Tags: jenkins

I am working in Jenkins and using their CLI to update plugins. I am running the command java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://examplejenkins8080/ -webSocket install-plugin examplePluginName and outputs "ERROR: anonymous is missing the Overall/Read permission".

I found out I am in anonymous on the cli but want to change that to my credentials. The command to sign in on cli is "-webSocket -auth -USER -Pass" but I don't want to show my password. Is there a way around this using a command to not show my password?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to pass credentials.

**Option 1**

Setting credentials as environment variables.

```
export JENKINS_USER_ID=kohsuke
export JENKINS_API_TOKEN=abc1234ffe4a
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar [-s JENKINS_URL] command ...
```

**Option 2**

Load credentials from a file. In this case you can save the credentials as USER:PASSWORD in a file and then point to that file.

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar [-s JENKINS_URL] -auth @/home/kohsuke/.jenkins-cli command ...
```

For more info check [this](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/) document.